How to setup new APC UPS against linux Debian 10 HPC
We have Linux Debian 10 cluster. We want to connect it to a new UPS (APC) to have power outage protection for the cluster.
However, APC suggested installing PowerChtue software. Contrarily this software is compatible with the RedHat Linux Enterprise and SuSe Linux Enterprise only.
I found apcupsd service which can be used as an alternative ways. We have NIS conenction as per the apcuspd guideline.
Error obtained after setting it up:

Still, I can not understand where should I put the ip address of the cluster and how set up further communication between the cluster and UPS?
Please sugegst and let me know if I need to furnish further details to facilitate the process.
thanks

You need to split this up into different parts.
Assuming this UPS is compatible with apcupsd and has a USB port...
Firstly you need a single machine connected to the UPS's USB port.  On that machine configure it to talk to the USB port
eg
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE

(yes, the device entry is empty; the daemon finds the USB connection automatically).
Now you should be able to start apcupsd on that one machine and it should work.  apcaccess should then show some useful data
APC      : 001,038,0997
DATE     : 2024-10-07 13:30:09 -0400
HOSTNAME : myhostname
VERSION  : apcupsd_version
UPSNAME  : myhostname
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2024-08-18 08:37:30 -0400
MODEL    : Back-UPS XS 1500M
STATUS   : ONLINE

If this part fails then either your cabling is bad, or the UPS doesn't support remote monitoring, or you have some other issue.
Once this is working then you can start to look at the NIS side of things.
First configure this machine to be the NIS server:
NETSERVER on
NISIP 0.0.0.0
NISPORT 3551

Restart the server and you should then see it listening.
% ss -an | grep 3551
tcp   LISTEN 0      5                                                                            0.0.0.0:3551             0.0.0.0:*

Now you can configure the other machines to talk to this
UPSNAME yourUPSname
UPSCABLE ether
UPSTYPE net
DEVICE remoteserverIPaddress

NETSERVER on
NISIP 0.0.0.0
NISPORT 3551

Start apcupsd on the client and apcaccess should show the connection
UPSNAME  : remoteservername
CABLE    : Ethernet Link
DRIVER   : NETWORK UPS Driver

You can add many clients and they can all talk to the single server.
At least this works for me!
NOTE: this is inherently not "cluster" because the UPS can only connect to a single machine via USB, so you have a single point of failure (what if that machine goes down?) and the IP address is the address of that single machine.

Thanks for this descriptive suggestions. I will try out and get back.

Thanks @Stephen Harris. The Linux debian cluster which was connected to the UPS by USB cable was able to communicate with the UPS .
I edited the  ["apcupsd.conf"] file on the cluster which was USB connected to the UPS.
Now, [apcaccess] looks like :
APC      : 001,027,0689
DATE     : 2024-10-11 15:00:02 +0100
HOSTNAME : ib-server
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) debian
UPSNAME  : ib-server
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2024-10-11 14:41:35 +0100
MODEL    : Smart-UPS SRT
STATUS   : ONLINE

apcupsd.conf file on the Linux cluster which is USB connected to UPS looks like :
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE
NETSERVER on
NISIP 0.0.0.0
NISPORT 3551

Sorry for asking again.
I still can not get how can I make the UPS visible to another server. This server is different and not USB connected to the UPS.
As you said, we can addas many clients to talk to the UPS.
Do I need to edit the apcupsd.conf file on the new client which is say ether UPSCABLE connected to the UPS or on the same apcupsd.conf file created on the previous linux Debian cluster. If the same file is to be used, then please let me know how can I ensure that another serevr sees the UPS.
Please sugegst.

The client needs to be configured different to the server; I showed an example with these 4 entries; UPSNAME yourUPSname UPSCABLE ether UPSTYPE net DEVICE remoteserverIPaddress.  This is how the client talks to the NIS server, which is the one talking to the UPS.

Thanks. I am trying this now. I am supposed to make apcupsd.conf file on each cluster against which I want connect the UPS. I have two linux clusters which I wish to connect to one UPS.

I've always used the "Network UPS Tools" software: nut-client, nut-server, nut-cgi, and a few more these days.  It works with many brands of UPS.

Thanks. "apcupsd" service was previously installed on the Linux cluster. Only recently when previous UPS went off and we replaced it with a new UPS, the problem started. I am trying to set up the new UPS. However, still the cluster can not see the UPS with lost communication.

Unfortunately this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494295/apcupsd-on-debian-stretch-9-no-connection-to-ups?rq=1 does not work for me.
Still, the communication with UPS is lost. Please advice.

But that may be the answer:  in replacing a UPS you must update any and all configuration entries that refer to the old UPS to refer to the new UPS.  This could be DEVICE changing from a serial UPS to a USB one.  It could be model names.  It could be USB IDs.  You might compare your current configuration files with the ones provided by the original debian package.

Thanks. But, the new UPS model number is similar to the old UPS. Moreoevr, the cables cming out of the old clusters and connecetd to the old UPS were reused and those cables were only used to connect to the new UPS.

Following upto this issue, we have another UPS connecting othr sets of clusters. I have not changed the UPS but the old USB cable with a new longer USB cable. In that scenario also, I am getting error :
root@ib-server:~# apcaccess status
Error contacting apcupsd @ localhost:3551: Connection refused

The added error to the aforesaid cluster UPS:
root@ib-server:~# /etc/init.d/apcupsd restart
Stopping UPS power management: apcupsd.
Starting UPS power management: apcupsd.
Broadcast Message from admin@ib-serve
(somewhere) at 13:45 ...
Warning communications lost with UPS ib-server

"similar to"?  Could the new one perhaps be "MODBUS" or "MODBUS over USB" requiring a different UPSTYPE entry?  Or could the wrong serial number be specified?  (based on reading apcupsd.conf)
